# How to reverse only words of a specific length in a string(JS)?

Tags: javascript, split, reverse

**Write a function that takes in a string of one or more words, and returns the same string, but with all five or more letter words reversed. Strings passed in will consist of only letters and spaces. Spaces will be included only when more than one word is present.**

```js
 function spinWords(string){
    
    //splits string into words separated by a space
    var splitStringArray = string.split(" ");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++) {
    //if the word is more than 5 chars, reverse the word
     if (splitStringArray[i].length >= 5) {
      splitStringArray[i].split("").reverse().join("");
     }
    
    } //end for loop
    
    //join the modified array
    var joinString = splitStringArray.join(" ");
    
    return joinString;
    
    } //end function
    
    console.log(spinWords("Hey fellow students"));
```

I am unable to get the words with 5 or more chars reversed. I am trying to first split the string into an array of strings. Then I try to evaluate the length of each string in that array. If the length of the word is 5 or more, then I want to split, reverse, and join that word. Then I want to join the array and display the output.

The output should be "Hey wollef stneduts".

Comment: `splitStringArray[i].split("").reverse().join("");` - you need to assign this back to the array element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is correct, since strings in javascript are immutable, so you need to assign back the value. Simply change line:

```
splitStringArray[i].split("").reverse().join("");
```

To

```
splitStringArray[i]=splitStringArray[i].split("").reverse().join("");
```

```js
function spinWords(string){

//splits string into words separated by a space
var splitStringArray = string.split(" ");

for (var i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++) {
//if the word is more than 5 chars, reverse the word
    if (splitStringArray[i].length >= 5) {
        splitStringArray[i]= splitStringArray[i].split("").reverse().join("");
    }

} //end for loop

//join the modified array
var joinString = splitStringArray.join(" ");

return joinString;

}   //end function

console.log(spinWords("Hey fellow students"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not updated the array with the reverse value.
Just assign it back in loop

```js
 function spinWords(string){
    
    //splits string into words separated by a space
    var splitStringArray = string.split(" ");
    
    for (var i = 0; i < splitStringArray.length; i++) {
    //if the word is more than 5 chars, reverse the word
     if (splitStringArray[i].length >= 5) {
           splitStringArray[i]=splitStringArray[i].split("").reverse().join("");
     }
    
    } //end for loop
    
    //join the modified array
    var joinString = splitStringArray.join(" ");
    
    return joinString;
    
    } //end function
    
    console.log(spinWords("Hey fellow students"));
```